# compile python executable to work outside of main python directory

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, packaging

I am working on packaging and distributing some python applications in Windows by wrapping together a python runtime, the python packages for the applications, and some executables to run the python applications.  The approach is just to modify the source for python.exe to launch the applications but accept command line arguments for things like data file names.

Below is an example C++ source for one of the executables:

```cpp
// source for my_python_application1

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Python.h"

wchar_t SWITCH[] = L"-m";
wchar_t APP[] = L"my_python_application1.main";

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv) {

    int newargc;
    newargc = argc + 2;

    // can use this to modify the PythonPath for specific distributions
    // _putenv("PYTHONPATH=\"\"");

    wchar_t **newargv = new wchar_t*[newargc];
    newargv[0] = argv[0];
    newargv[1] = SWITCH;
    newargv[2] = APP;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        newargv[i + 2] = argv[i];
    }
    return Py_Main(newargc, newargv);
    // return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

Functionally this achieves everything I need it to achieve, but I suffer from a certain OCD nature which leads me to want things organized in a certain way.  I'd like to have a structure like the following

```
/application_suite
    /python_runtime
        python.exe
        python36.dll
        (and everything else in a python dir)
    /python_applications
    my_python_application1.exe
    my_python_application2.exe
```

However, since `mypythonapplication1/2.exe` are basically modified python.exe files, in order for them to work properly (load the python dll, import modules, access all of the landmarking features necessary for modules to be interconnected) they need to be located in the /python_runtime directory.

I'm wondering is there a way to compile these executables so that they can be arranged in the directory structure that I presented, but know that they python_runtime directory and all of its structure are located in a relative path of './python_runtime' or whatever so that this all behaves well no matter where the distribution of applications is installed by the end user.

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-Answer Warning** I am not a C/C++ programmer.  It is possible there are bad C++ practices in here, so please use what you find in this answer with a grain of salt.

The requirements to achieve this behavior are the following:

1. We must get the directory of the custom executable
2. We must set the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable to `%executable_dir%\runtime`
3. We must set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to `%executable_dir%\apps` so that python knows where our python packages are living.  This also clears out any system wide settings so that the distribution doesn't use other python environment settings
4. I don't know if it's necessary, but I am adding the `runtime` directory at the front of the path
5. We have to dynamically load the `Py_Main` function from the desired dll.  Since we are not expecting the runtime to be on the path before execution, we must find the dll dynamically from `%executable_dir%\runtime\python36.dll`.

The following source code works when I compiled in Visual Studio 2017, with no Python Header files and no dll specified in the Linker

```
// source code for custom my_python_application1
// requires _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS flag to compile deprecated path operations

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Shlwapi.h"
// #include "Python.h"  // don't need this as we are dynamically loading the library of choice

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
__pragma(warning(disable:4996))  // # _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECIATE

wchar_t SWITCH[] = L"-m";
wchar_t APP[] = L"my_python_application1.main";

typedef int(__stdcall *py_main_function)(int, wchar_t**);

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv) {

    int newargc;
    newargc = argc + 2;

    // determine the path of the executable so we know the absolute path
    // of the python runtime and application directories
    wchar_t executable_dir[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, executable_dir, MAX_PATH) == 0)
        return -1;
    PathRemoveFileSpec(executable_dir);
    std::wstring executable_dir_string(executable_dir);

    // now set the relevant environment variables so that the environment works as it is supposed to
    std::wstring python_home(L"PYTHONHOME=" + executable_dir_string + L"\\runtime");
    _wputenv(python_home.c_str());

    std::wstring python_path(L"PYTHONPATH=" + executable_dir_string + L"\\apps");
    _wputenv(python_path.c_str());

    // put the python runtime at the front of the path
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << "PATH=" << executable_dir << "\\runtime;" << getenv("PATH");
    std::wstring path_string (ss.str());
    _wputenv(path_string.c_str());

    wchar_t **newargv = new wchar_t*[newargc];
    newargv[0] = argv[0];
    newargv[1] = SWITCH;
    newargv[2] = APP;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        newargv[i + 2] = argv[i];
    }

    // dynamically load the python dll
    std::wstring python_dll(executable_dir_string + L"\\runtime\\python36.dll");
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(python_dll.c_str());
    py_main_function Py_Main = (py_main_function)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "Py_Main");

    //now call Py_Main with our arguments
    return Py_Main(newargc, newargv);
    // return Py_Main(argc, argv);

}
```